# Proper configuration for Windows SMTP Virtual Server to only send email from localhost, and tracking down source of spam emails

Tags: windows-server-2003, spam, smtp

We manage a server that is hosted on Amazon EC2, which has web applications that need to be able to send outgoing email.  Recently we received a notice from Amazon about possible email abuse on that server, so i've been looking into it.

It's Windows Server Datacenter (2003, i guess), and uses SMTP Virtual Server (you know, the one that requires IIS 6 for admin).  The settings on the Access tab are as follows:
 - Authentication: Anonymous
 - Connection: Only from 3 ip addresses (127.0.0.1 and 2 others that refer to that server)
 - Relay: Only from 3 ip addresses (127.0.0.1 and 2 others that refer to that server)

In the SMTP logs there are many entries like the following:

2012-02-08 23:43:56 64.76.125.151 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 FROM: 0 0 4 0 26364 SMTP - - - -
2012-02-08 23:43:56 64.76.125.151 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 250+ok 0 0 6 0 26536 SMTP - - - -
2012-02-08 23:43:56 64.76.125.151 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 TO: 0 0 4 0 26536 SMTP - - - -
2012-02-08 23:43:56 64.76.125.151 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 250+ok 0 0 6 0 26707 SMTP - - - -

(kenrocks71@yahoo.com is sending quite a lot of emails :-/)

Can anyone confirm if the SMTP server settings seem correct?

I'm also wondering if a web application on the machine could be exposing a contact form or something that would allow this sort of abuse, looking into that (and how to look into that) further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling onto this, in our case the SMTP server settings do appear to be correct.  There was a web application on that server which was trusted to send email and was exposing a form that allowed emails to be sent out, and adding a reCaptcha to that form stopped the abuse.